# Add current date to the report we are extracting from database using Sailpoint rule in xml

Tags: java, xml, sailpoint

Add current date to the report we are extracting from database using xml
File name is as below, we need to have CIMO_Data06232021.csv
String CSV_FILE_PATH="E:\CIMO_Data.csv";

Comment: which sailpoint product we're talking about here?

Comment: Not only what product are we talking about - but what code have you put together, and what is falling? Are you asking about putting it in a workflow? Are you iterating over it during a task? An aggregation?  a rule? Context would be helpful as well.